# Narrow string literal type dynamically based on code

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Sorry if the title is not accurate, It's kind of a weird question.

I have the following code:

```js
enum LogType {
  file = "file",
  http = "http",
  database = "database"
}

interface LoggerDetails {
  // ... bunch of properties
  provider: "datadog" | "log4j" | "newrelic"
}

interface Logger {
  type: LogType;
  provider: LoggerDetails["provider"];
}


interface NetworkLogger extends Logger {
  type: LogType.http,
  provider: "datadog"
}

interface FileLogger extends Logger {
  type: LogType.file,
  provider: "log4j"
}

type LoggerKey = `${LogType}.${Logger["provider"]}`;

// type LegalLoggerKeys = Extract<LoggerKey, "http.datadog" | "file.log4j">;// <-- This works, but hard coded. Also, it requires us to write it down for every new logger interface
type LegalLoggerKeys = unknown; // ?? 

// should only accept 'http.datadog' and 'file.log4j' as keys using the interfaces that extends Logger 
const record: Record<LegalLoggerKeys, (message: string) => void> = {

}
```

My goal is to create `LegalLoggerKeys` using the interfaces `FileLogger`, `NetworkLogger`, or any other implementation. as you can see my commented code, I was able to do it with hard coded string literals.

Is it possible to create the same thing using the interfaces?
[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wgAjBm)

Comment: You need to maintain a list of known loggers yourself, but then you can extract the keys you're talking about, as shown [in this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nnevow). Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It does, Thank you! please write the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler won't be able to automatically discover all interfaces declared to extend `Logger`, so you'll need to maintain such a list yourself manually.  One way to do that is with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
type KnownLoggers = NetworkLogger | FileLogger // <-- maintain this manually
```

---

Once you have such a union, you can manipulate it to generate the union of acceptable keys.  If you have a single logger type `L` that extends `Logger`, you can compute the allowed key via the [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html):

```
type LoggerKey<L extends Logger> = `${L['type']}.${L['provider']}`;

type NetworkLoggerKey = LoggerKey<NetworkLogger>;
// type NetworkLoggerKey = "http.datadog"
```

But if you have a *union* of logger types, this won't behave the way you want, since each piece of that concatenated string will be split into unions separately:

```
type KnownLoggerKeys = LoggerKey<KnownLoggers>
// type KnownLoggerKeys = "file.datadog" | "file.log4j" | "http.datadog" | "http.log4j"
```

Oops.

---

So we will need to tweak the definition of `LoggerKey` so that it *distributes* its operation across unions in its input.  We can do this by expressing it as a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type LoggerKey<L extends Logger> =
  L extends Logger ? `${L['type']}.${L['provider']}` : never;
```

Note that the check `L extends Logger ?` isn't really useful as a check; the compiler already knows that `L` is constrained to `Logger`.  But it serves as a directive to split `L` up into its union members before evaluation and then to re-unite into a new union afterward.

And so now we have:

```
type KnownLoggerKeys = LoggerKey<KnownLoggers>
// type KnownLoggerKeys = "http.datadog" | "file.log4j"
```

as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-kqUHrPn6aQSiT6FdptZV8FSdh6Q97A8q9Tx2GhDnJvL41ECMFAMVicb7lXj5bkg-nsbjtUwY3KK4Xw36SzR3umvLdItQIYdgghwp2Uxw2zdfKTB2ne-2oIBeDcAcjtqAZyxMqtXfTUbf668hMVcatYb8NQAD8Brt5st1ttJvNjp0zv1UA8MUcOjddcxlaLKBLy5p9arOC1h6-5fs2JzDpmdxjt2k6IjgQA)